# Azure DevOps Pipelines: Newman the cli Companion for Postman on a self-hosted agent (Windows)

Tags: azure-devops, postman, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-pipelines

I am using the task "Newman the cli Companion for Postman" ([Link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=carlowahlstedt.NewmanPostman)) in a YAML pipeline to run Postman collections for testing and warm up purposes.

I use the task like the following:

```
- task: carlowahlstedt.NewmanPostman.NewmanPostman.NewmanPostman@4
  displayName: 'Newman - Postman'
  inputs:
    collectionFileSource: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/Postman'
    Contents: '**\*_collection.json'
    folder: Release
    environment: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/Postman/$(Environment).postman_environment.json'
    ignoreRedirect: false
    bail: false
    sslInsecure: false
    reporters: 'html,junit'
    reporterHtmlExport: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/Postman'
    htmlExtraDarkTheme: false
    htmlExtraLogs: false
    htmlExtraTestPaging: false
    reporterJUnitExport: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/Postman'
```

Doing so on a hosted agent works fine but when working with a self-hosted one I get:

```
##[error]Unable to locate executable file: 'newman'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also verify the file has a valid extension for an executable file.
```

I have newman as well as newman-reporter-html installed on the agent and am able to run it when logged in to the agent.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: "I have newman as well as newman-reporter-html installed on the agent and am able to run it when logged in to the agent."
  
I assume you mean your self-hosted agent in the sentence above. What command did you use to install newman?

Comment: `npm install -g newman` and `npm install -g newman-reporter-html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve the issue I added

```
pathToNewman: 'C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm\newman.cmd'
```

to the task definition. The path is used if no version is found by the agent.

As a result the task looks then like

```
- task: carlowahlstedt.NewmanPostman.NewmanPostman.NewmanPostman@4
  displayName: 'Newman - Postman'
  inputs:
    collectionFileSource: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/Postman'
    Contents: '**\*_collection.json'
    folder: Release
    environment: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/Postman/$(Environment).postman_environment.json'
    pathToNewman: 'C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm\newman.cmd'
    ignoreRedirect: false
    bail: false
    sslInsecure: false
    reporters: 'html,junit'
    reporterHtmlExport: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/Postman'
    htmlExtraDarkTheme: false
    htmlExtraLogs: false
    htmlExtraTestPaging: false
    reporterJUnitExport: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/Postman'
```

I am not sure why it is not finding the installed version itself. So if somebody has an idea it would be great to share.